# how to Add $request_uri to auth_request module?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, auth-request

Here is my nginx config file:

```
location ~* ^/admin-panel/rest/(.*) {
    auth_request        /admin/admin_authentication/check_access?url=$request_uri;

    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    proxy_pass        http://nginx:8000/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

I want to send `$request_uri` as a `GET` parameter to my authentication service. but i get errors like this:

```
2019/06/23 06:30:07 [error] 6#6: *5 auth request unexpected status: 
404 while sending to client, client: 192.168.224.1, server: , request: 
"POST /admin-panel/rest/update HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2019/06/23 06:30:07 [error] 6#6: *8 auth request unexpected status: 
404 while sending to client, client: 192.168.224.1, server: , request: 
"POST /admin-panel/rest/update HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2019/06/23 06:31:56 [error] 6#6: *1 auth request unexpected status: 
404 while sending to client, client: 192.168.224.1, server: , request: 
"POST /admin-panel/rest/update HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2019/06/23 06:31:57 [error] 6#6: *3 auth request unexpected status: 
404 while sending to client, client: 192.168.224.1, server: , request: 
"POST /admin-panel/rest/update HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

when I remove `?url=$request_uri` section in `auth_request`, everything works fine

Comment: Maybe you can use `set_by_lua`  to create the URI argument for `auth_request`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) (or [openresty](https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty) docker image), You can use `access_by_lua_block` instead of `auth_request` like this:

```
location ~* ^/admin-panel/rest/(.*) {
    access_by_lua_block {
        local res = ngx.location.capture("/admin/admin_authentication/check_access?url=" .. ngx.var.request_uri)

        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
            return
        end

        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN then
            ngx.exit(res.status)
        end

        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }

    proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    proxy_pass        http://nginx:8000/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Actually, This code implements `auth_request` with `access_by_lua_block` and create URL with Lua concatenation operator `..`.